# IntelliJ - select one word in text "FirstSecondThirdFourth"

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

How to select the word "Second" in the text "FirstSecondThirdFourth" when the keyboard pointer is placed on the word "Second" (or at the beginning of the word "Second" - between 't' and 'S')? Is there any shortcut? It would be very helpful when changing the name of the function or variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure **Use "CamelHumps" words** option is enabled in Settings(Preferences) | Editor | General | [Smart Keys](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-smart-keys.html);
2. Use Main menu | Edit | [**Extend Selection**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-code-editor.html#edit_code) action and corresponding shortcut.

Comment: Don't know why but my Android Studio as well as IntelliJ had disabled this option.

Answer (score 0):

At least in Android Studio, you can get close by adding a key mapping.  In Settings/Keymap, look for Editor Actions/Move Caret to Next Word with Selection in Different "CamelHumps" Mode.